# What does the function name `ravel` stand for in `NumPy`?

Tags: python, numpy

What does `ravel` stand for in `NumPy`?

Sometimes, it is a bit harder to remember a function name that the name has nothing to do with its description.

Answer (score 7):

The dictionary meaning for `ravel` is

```
to become unwoven, untwisted, or unwound
```

We tend to use `unravel` in same way

```
to separate or undo the texture of : UNRAVEL
```

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ravel

In `numpy` `flatten` does the same thing, except it always makes a copy.  `ravel` is more like `reshape(-1)`, returning a `view` where possible

It's use for computational arrays may trace back to `apl` in the 1960s.

https://aplwiki.com/wiki/Ravel.

Answer (score 3):

`ravel` means the same as `unravel` - **to become unwoven, untwisted, or unwound**

As for [numpy ravel](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) - a **1-D array**, containing the elements of the input, is returned. So if you provide a 2D array to `ravel`, it will be unwoven, untwisted or unwound, to become a 1D array.

```py
x = np.array([[1, 2, 3], 
              [4, 5, 6]])
np.ravel(x)

OUTPUT:
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
```